# phpunit Error: Class 'Prophecy\Prophet' not found

Tags: composer-php, phpunit, prophecy

I am in the process of writing some PHPUnit tests in Prophecy with the following code:

```
public function testItBuildsAndPersistsEnclosure()
{
   $em = $this->prophesize(EntityManagerInterface::class);
}
```

Which yields me the following output:

> PHPUnit 6.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Testing Project Test Suite E.
>   2 / 2 (100%)
>
> Time: 105 ms, Memory: 6.00MB
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1)
>   Tests\AppBundle\Service\EnclosureBuilderServiceProphecyTest::testItBuildsAndPersistsEnclosure
>   Error: Class 'Prophecy\Prophet' not found

I'm a bit new to PHPUnit and testing in general but as I understand it, PHPUnit is supposed to have [built-in support](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.prophecy) for using Prophecy which makes the error above really surprising.

I tried installing [phpspec/prophecy](https://packagist.org/packages/phpspec/prophecy) but that process failed as shown below:

```
composer require phpspec/prophecy

Using version ^1.10 for phpspec/prophecy
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 9.0.1
    - Conclusion: remove doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ^9.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[9.0.0, 9.0.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0
    - phpunit/phpunit 9.0.0 requires doctrine/instantiator ^1.2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/instantiator[1.2.0, 1.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/instantiator[1.2.0, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/instantiator[1.3.0, 1.1.0].
    - Installation request for doctrine/instantiator (locked at 1.1.0) -> satisfiable by doctrine/instantiator[1.1.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: Why do you want to install PHPUnit over Composer in v9.0 while your console output lists v6.5.14? And are you sure that the given test line (which does not instantiate `Prophet`) triggers that error?

Comment: @NicoHaase: Yes, I am very sure Prophet is the reason for the error.

Comment: And may I ask why you don't upgrade your doctrine/instantiator?